# jquery sortable / draggable bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

having a little issue with something today. I have a table that is set to sortable with items being the tr rows and each having a handle column with arrow icon.

my main problem is that when I mousedown & drag on handle it highlights all of the text in the div/table, it takes sometimes 2-3 attempts of doing this mouse drag before it picks it up and moves it.

I'm completely beating my head in trying to figure out what could be causing this or a simple work around. There aren't any other events triggering that would be interfering as far as I know.

Any ideas/suggestions? I was thinking perhaps there is a way to manually start dragging on mousedown on the handle, but I have been unsuccessful getting it to work.

Comment: Can you throw your code into a jsFiddle so we can help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the elements unselectable in your CSS

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
user-select: none;
```